# Tangent point of sphere and circle

Tags: circles, spheres

I would like to know parametric equation of the tangent point of a sphere and a circle. Circle center point is $(a,b,c)$ and its radius is $K$. Sphere center point is $(d,e,f)$ and its radius is $L$.

I assume that specified circle and a sphere intersect on one tangent point. I would like to know how I can determine the tangent point $(x,y,z)$.

If there is a misinformation please define for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wondering about the determination of a circle tangent to a sphere given its respective centers, the plane of the circle and the ray of the sphere?

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the intersection of two spheres.

Comment: I exactly want to find the cartesian coordinate of the tangent point regarding to given center point and radius of sphere and circle.

Comment: A circle outside a sphere and touching it could be rotated about the axis between their centers and trace a circle on the sphere orthogonal to that axis. Is that what you want? As @amd says, this is the circle of intersection of 2 spheres.

Comment: Actually, I think that the question can be asked for intersection point of two spheres. Because circle and sphere have same equations. But I would like to know one specific point that they are tangent. Because if the spheres intersect with each other, it will have two intersection point. But I need only one tangent point.

Answer (score 0):

In the plane passing through the centers $A,B$ and the tangent point $C$, you get a triangle $ABC$ of which you know the three sides.
So you can determine every parameter of it, and in particular the height $h$ from $C$ to the side $AB$.

When reported in $3$D, the triangle is free to rotate around the axis $AB$ and the point C can be whichever along a circle on the sphere of radius $h$ from the $AB$ axis.

You need one more constraint to fix the circle.

Comment: I know the plane equation of the circle that is lying on. On the other hand, the two intersection points can be useful for me.

Comment: @onur: if  the plane of the circle is known, then the plane $ABC$ is also known as being normal to the first. Then the problem is much easier: please specify exactly what is known and what is to be determined.